# Emacs: Is it possible to browse images in a directory? On Windows?

Tags: image, emacs

I read about auto-image-file-mode , which I think displays image files as images within emacs.  I'd like to use it.  [This doc](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoImageFileMode) says it has been replaced by image-mode.

I can't get either to work.

Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got it to work, by downloading the packages for PNG and JPG [from GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html), and putting the required DLLs into the \emacs\bin directory:

```
From LibPng: 
  libpng-config
  libpng12-config
  libpng12.dll
  libpng3.dll
  zlib1.dll

From jpeg: 
  jpeg62.dll
```

Now it works. Here's a screen-shot of editing a SO question, being displayed in emacs.

[image]

You could also drop those DLLs on the OS's PATH, before running runemacs.exe. That works, too.

Comment: Works great, though zlib1.dll isn't provided in the png zip file (binaries at least).

Comment: yeah, weird, it was for me, for v1.2.3.6. I think it's necessary.

Comment: Are there any pass-through commands to the image-displays, that would allow us to size the image to fit, etc? I can scroll the image, but hi-res file are tough to view....

Comment: I don't know; it might be worthy of a new question. On the other hand, as not very programming related, it would be in danger of getting closed pretty quickly! (like this one)

Answer (score 2):

It can depend on what version and where you got your windows emacs binary. If you have the windows emacs23 binary from the gnu ftp site then I don't think it is compiled with image support (at least this was the case several months ago). I use the patched windows emacs23 binary from [EmacsW32](http://www.ourcomments.org/Emacs/EmacsW32.html) which does have image support. I also have `(auto-image-file-mode)` in my `.emacs` file.

Answer (score 0):

Using Emacs 23.1 (on Fedora 12) when I visit a `*.png` file, it shows up as an image in the Emacs buffer.  Similarly for `*.gif` and `*.pdf` files.  The mode was advertised as Image[png], fwiw.

Comment: Interesting, but that doesn't help me at all.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've gotten Emacs to show images, you can also see thumbnail images in these contexts, in addition to Dired (using `image-dired`):

- In buffer `*Completions*` during file-name completion or completion of (file) bookmarks.  You need [***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles) for this. Showing the thumbnails is optional -- you can toggle it from the minibuffer using <kbd>C-x t</kbd> (cycles among: showing only images, images + file names, and only file names).
- In buffer `*Bookmark List*` (from <kbd>C-x r l</kbd>), when you hit <kbd>C-h RET</kbd> to see info about the current line's bookmark.  You need [***Bookmark+***](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/BookmarkPlus) for this.

[bookmarks](/questions/tagged/bookmarks)[bookmark](/questions/tagged/bookmark)